# How to modify the picture size using OpenCV for Android?

Tags: android, opencv

Does anybody know how to modify the picture size using OpenCV for Android ?

It seems that sizes are set to a maximum that I didn't managed to change.
Using the tutorial ImageManipulations which is based on JavaCameraView, here are the maximum resolutions that I can get:
camera Preview Size. Width: 960 Height : 720
camera Picture Size. Width: 640 Height : 480

The problem is that I need a much higher resolution for the picture (I don't care about the preview size).

Maybe there's an answer in the opencv forum but I can't access to this answer since it seems there are works over there ([OpenCVForum](http://answers.opencv.org/question/1742/how-to-set-camera-resolution-in-opencv-on-android/))

Answer (score 0):

You can resize a Mat as follows:

```
    Size szSource = new Size(640,480);
    Size szResized = new Size(2592,1944);
    Mat mSource= new Mat(szSource, CvType.CV_8U);// Read or Fill Something in your mSource
    Mat mResised = new Mat();
    Imgproc.resize( mSource, mResised, szResized,0,0,INTER_NEAREST);//mSource-> Your Source image

interpolation – interpolation method can be any of the above
INTER_NEAREST - a nearest-neighbor interpolation
INTER_LINEAR - a bilinear interpolation (used by default)
INTER_AREA - resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a preferred method for image decimation, as it gives moire’-free results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to the INTER_NEAREST method.
INTER_CUBIC - a bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood
INTER_LANCZOS4 - a Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 pixel neighborhood
```

For further reference [please see this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize).

Comment: Thanks Balaji but I want to increase the quality of the picture otherwise the analysis I want to do on the photo cannot be done. So it's really the picture size in pixels that I want to increase.

Comment: This is a good workaround but the quality of the pictureremains too low for the remaining tasks. What I really would like is to act on the camera parameters with SetPictureSize. Anyway thanks a lot for your help Balaji. I appreciate